# Haskell Monad Beginner

Tags: haskell

Hello I have a code which I'm trying to understand:

```
zipM:: Monad m => [m a] -> [m b] -> m [(a,b)]
zipM [] list = return []
zipM list [] = return []
zipM (hFirst:tFirst) (hSecond:tSecond) = do
  rest <- zipM tFirst tSecond
  headUnpacked <- unpack hFirst hSecond
  return (headUnpacked : rest) -- rest = Just []

unpack ::Monad m => m a -> m b -> m (a,b)
unpack first second = do
  fi <- first
  se <- second
  return (fi, se)
```

Generally I got a point but still have problem at two moments.

1. How to  call 'unpack' in console ?  I tried   `unpack (Just 5)` and it's causing an error.
2. Since `'rest'`  is `'Just []'`  how can I perform simple list add?
   I tried `(Just 4): (Just [])` and also `(Just [1,2]): (Just [2,3])` both of which result in errors.

I'll be most grateful if someone will show with some basic explanation how to perform this two actions.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: 1)  * No instance for (Show (Maybe b0 -> Maybe (a0, b0)))
        arising from a use of `show'
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    * In the expression: show (unpack (Just 5))
      In an equation for `it': it = show (unpack (Just 5))
2.1)* Couldn't match expected type `[Maybe a]'
                  with actual type `Maybe [t0]'

2.2)for (Just [1,2]): (Just [2,3]) --Couldn't match expected type `[Maybe [t]]'
                  with actual type `Maybe [Integer]'

Comment: That message tells you exactly what the problem is.  Did you follow its advice?

Comment: I find it a bit weird to start with monads (which is usually seen as an intermediate or advanced topic) whereas this question shows that calling functions based on the type signature is a problem.

Comment: As the error reports: `maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unpack` in GHCi like this:

```
Prelude> unpack (Just 5) (Just 42)
Just (5,42)
Prelude> unpack [[42,1337],[123]] [["foo"],["bar","baz"]]
[([42,1337],["foo"]),([42,1337],["bar","baz"]),([123],["foo"]),([123],["bar","baz"])]
Prelude> :m +Data.Monoid
Prelude Data.Monoid> unpack (Product 7, "foo") (Product 6, "bar")
(Product {getProduct = 42},("foo","bar"))
```

Notice that the function works with any `Monad`, not only `Maybe`. The above GHCi session demonstrates that by also calling `unpack` with two lists, and two tuples (which are `Monad` instances when the first element is a `Monoid`).

There's nothing inherently wrong with the expression `unpack (Just 5)`:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> :t unpack (Just 5)
unpack (Just 5) :: Num a => Maybe b -> Maybe (a, b)
```

The reason you see an error is because, as you can see from the above type inquiry, the expression is *a function*. Again, there's nothing wrong with functions, but GHCi doesn't know how to render functions because it relies on the `Show` type class to turn expressions into printable values, and functions don't have `Show` instances.

To address the second question, `rest` isn't `Just []`. First, `Just` isn't a type, but a data constructor, but secondly, even if you meant `Maybe [a]`, that's not necessarily true, because you don't know whether or not the `Monad` in question is `Maybe` or some other `Monad`.

Finally, as far as I can tell, `rest` is the result of calling `unpack`, the result of which has the type `Monad m => m (a,b)`. Since `rest` is bound using `do` notation, it must, then, have the type `(a,b)`, unless I'm mistaken.